# Combinatorial Proof of $\binom{n+1}{k} = (n+1)\binom{n}{k-1}/k$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

When n and k are positive integers.

Would this be a correct proof?

Description: Suppose how many ways can we choose k people from a group of n + 1.

LHS: The left-hand side gives us the number of ways to do this by definition, on how to select k from n+1.

RHS: The right-hand side gives us the number of ways to do this as well, but instead, it first counts the number of elements plus one (n+1) times the number of ways to choose an element a subset of k - 1 in n over the number of elements k.

Comment: Your argument for RHS was just narrating the arithmetic on that side.  It never explains why it counts the number of ways to choose $k$ people from a group of $n+1$

Comment: @BrianMoehring I agree that it is narrating the arithmetic side of it - How would I transfer that into how it actually counts the number of ways to choose k from a group of n+1?

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to provide a combinatorial proof of

$$ \binom{k}{1} \binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n+1}{1} \binom{n}{k-1}$$.

Indeed, since $\binom{\ell}{1} = \ell$, we can apply this to $\ell = n,k$ and then move $k$ to the RHS (right-hand side).

Here's a combinatorial proof. The LHS counts ways of choosing a team of $k$ people from a total of $n+1$ people, and then picking one of those $k$ to be the leader. The RHS counts the number of ways of picking one leader of the $n+1$ people, and then $k-1$ followers from the remaining $n$ people.